# Onsen UIで遷移先のページを別htmlファイルとして用意する方法（非Angular）

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, cordova

Onsen UI（v2系）でSPAをつくっています。
AngularやVueなどのフレームワークを使わないで、構築しています。

ons-list-itemをクリックすると、hoge.htmlに遷移し、戻るボタンでまたindex.htmlに戻るとしたいです。このとき,hoge.htmlはindex.html内にtemplateとして書き込むのではなく、別ページ（別ファイル）として読み込みたいです。index.html内に書き込むやり方は公式サンプルがあるので、わかるのですが。
どうしてもやり方がわかりません。
よろしくご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

例えば、下記のような**template**の場合、

```
<template id="hoge.html">
  <ons-page>
    hoge
  </ons-page>
</template>
```

「**hoge.html**」を作成し、**ons-page**の内容を記述することで同じような動作となります。

**hoge.html**

```
<ons-page>
  hoge
</ons-page>
```